# Does new[] allocate memory contiguously?

Tags: c++, new-operator

When I use the new[] keyword (or new-operator), does it allocate memory contiguously?

```
int* arr = new int[10];
```

I mean, is there any guarantee, that *arr[0]* and *arr[1]* are closely placed, and I can iterate through the *arr* using pointer increments? If so, does this behavior save with structs and classes instead of int?

Comment: The physical memory may be allocated from scattered pages, but the virtual address space for the allocated memory will be continuous.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN: A silly thing for me to say these days but I can't resist: `std::vector` contiguity has only been guaranteed since C++03.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C++ standard *absolutely* guarantees this.

`arr[0]` through to `arr[9]` are contiguous with no padding allowed between elements. Pointer arithmetic is valid in the allocated region. You are allowed to set a pointer to `arr + 10`, but **don't** dereference it.

This applies to *any* class. The amount of memory allocated per element is `sizeof(Y)` where `Y` is the class or plain old data type.

Comment: You will get padding at the end of the struct/class to get the right alignment. But sizeof will include the padding, so yes the array will be contiguous.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN How do you propose to detect the presence of padding with `sizeof()`?

Comment: sizeof(YourClass) vs sum of sizeof(each data member)

Comment: So if I allocate, for example, 1000 arrays with 10000 elements each, is it possible, that next new[] can throw bad_alloc, cause of high memory defragmentation with no any continuous block that can contain 10000 elements?

Comment: @AlexLarionov yes that's possible. But on today's typical machines, it will require a lot more than 10000 elements or very large elements to reach that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the elements are guaranteed to be located in consectuive memory (independent of their type). When you call `new[]` you get an array and actually the only way to access the elements is via pointer arithmetics.

Consider what `arr[i]` actually means:

```
arr[i]
```

is really just a short form of

```
*( ( arr ) + (i) )
```

A quirky sideeffect of this, is that for an array `arr` and an index `i`

```
i[arr]
```

is exactly the same as `arr[i]` (though you would only write this if you want to confuse your coworkers).

However, note that `[]` can be overloaded and in that case it can do whatever the implementation chooses. Nevertheless, also an array allocated with `new[]` that has an overloaded `oeprator[]` will have its elements in consecutive memory.

Comment: There's no harm in borrowing text from my answer - SO works best if there are multiple answers.

Comment: Also, if you're concentrating on the `[]` notation, you might want to point out that it can be overloaded.

Comment: Ty for nice note. I just tried to make simple question, without actual implementation